# django-allauth - RESTful API return all email address belonging to a user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I'm trying to make serialization class which will return all email addresses belonging to a specific user, but I have no idea how to achieve that because in `django-allauth`, `emailaddress_set` is linked to the `User` model. The reason I want this is clear - I want to display an AJAX form (I'm using AngularJS) where email addresses can be altered.
Back to the topic - I was thinking of something like this, but obviously it wouldn't work:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers

UserModel = get_user_model()

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = '__all__'

class EmailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel.emailadress_set
        fields = '__all__'
```

And this is how class for email addresses consists in `django-allauth`:

```
class EmailAddress(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(allauth_app_settings.USER_MODEL,
                             verbose_name=_('user'))
    email = models.EmailField(unique=app_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL,
                              max_length=254,
                              verbose_name=_('e-mail address'))
    verified = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('verified'), default=False)
    primary = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('primary'), default=False)

    objects = EmailAddressManager()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will work

```
class EmailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_info = serializers.RelatedField(source='usermodel', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = EmailAddress
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'user_info')
```

Comment: Thanks for the class, it works even without `user_info` field!